# RegEXP: How to convert a one line while retaining some of the information per line?

Tags: regex, replace, editor, regex-group

Lets say I have the following:

```
ItemsDrop=Breastplate|1,Leopard Pelt|5,Jackal Hide|5,Fire Ember|0.01,Dim Fire Ember|0.025,Extinguished Fire Ember|0.065
```

and

```
ItemsDrop=Knife|1,Leopard Pelt|5,Night Ember|0.01,Dim Night Ember|0.025,Extinguished Night Ember|0.065
```

I want to be able to change the `'XXX Ember|0.01,Dim XXX Ember|0.025,Extinguished XXX Ember|0.065'` portion of the line using reg ex. Mainly so I can adjust it to something like

```
ItemsDrop=Breastplate|1,Leopard Pelt|5,Jackal Hide|5,Fire Ember|0.11,Dim Fire Ember|0.125,Extinguished Fire Ember|0.165
```

for example. `'Fire'` can be replaced with anything in general there, but they are always in a row like that, so it's always `'Fire Ember|0.11,Dim Fire Ember|0.125,Extinguished Fire Ember|0.165'` but can start at the beginning, middle, or end of the line.

Any ideas on this? I am aiming to replace 3000 or so files so it would be great to do it in one or two replacements!

Comment: What OS/database? Or is the data in  flat file? What tools are you intending on using? Not all regex implementations are created equally. Need more info.

Comment: Sorry about that. Windows, just using a text replace. flat files. (Using textpad or notepad++). Needing to replace about 5000 files or so.

I got (Dim .*? Ember|)(0.01) for the search and then $1(0.02) which replaces the Dim ember, but whenever I try to combine it for the full string I'm having issues.

Comment: I guess (.*? Ember|)(0.01)(.*?)(Dim .*? Ember|)(0.025)(.*?)(Extinguished .*? Ember|)0.065 could work as well actually.

Comment: Dim?  Are you using vb?  I was going to suggest a wrapper program around this as you certainly are not going to open 5000 files!  Are all the files in one folder?